# Charge at 24v and discharge at 12v for battery system

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, parallel, 12v, series

Is my thinking correct.

Below is a simple diagram of the concept I want to check.
[image]

Is this:
1: Possible
2: Feasible? I.E are there any concerns or foreseen issues with this design?

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to short out the top left-hand 12V battery? Also, why would you want to short out the top right hand battery? Is your concept about melting batteries or starting a fire?

Comment: It would need a few switches to avoid the short circuit Andy noticed, and some batteries don't like being connected in parallel (the weaker one tends to leech charge from the stronger) but in principle it COULD be OK. As long as you realise it can EITHER charge at 24V OR discharge at 12V and you can guarantee there is no way to (accidentally) set the switches for both. That could start a fire.

Comment: Why is there a short? I don't see where the batteries short out? Could you point it out to me? The idea is to charge with 24v and to discharge at 12v?

Comment: If you are going to use two batteries in parallel then you need to ensure that both batteries have the same amount of charge otherwise there will be big circulating current as one battery tries to charge the other. I'd advise against it.

Comment: Short 1: RHS battery wire from red terminal to 12V output then to red terminal of other battery and finally to black terminal of RHS battery: So in effect directly from red to black. There is a similar path for the other battery too.

Comment: @WarrenHill  Aaah I see. Ok that makes sense now. And in that case will my Diodes not help?

Comment: I can't see why the new circuit with diodes should not work but make sure each diode can handle the full load current because if one battery has more charge than the other it will provide all the current until it discharges to the same level as the other one.  Once its at the same level of charge both batteries will share the current.

Comment: So you would need very large Diodes to prevent the diode from failing. as if one battery discharges a fair amount than the other the you will have voltage difference * current trying to go through the diode?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13347/discussion-between-warren-hill-and-zapnologica)

Comment: The diodes do NOT help. Note very carefully how much (and what polarity) voltage is across each diode. Do you see why your "12V output" will actually have 24V (minus 2 diode drops) across it?

Comment: If you have never seen a 12v battery boil, burn, or explode, go spend 5 minutes on YouTube before you get the tools out and start wiring anything up.

Comment: Incidentally, this problem of 12v/24v from two batteries is quite common in the automotive world, cars being 12v, trucks being 24v, and some 4x4's (Land Cruisers, Defenders, esp. military ones) being dual-voltage and employing various methods for managing the split. No-one's come up with a really elegant answer yet as far as I can tell.

Comment: @John U Thanks, Its good to know im not the only one.

Comment: It would help if you clarified the criteria here: For example, a common problem might be running 12v devices in a 24v vehicle, so it's better to keep everything 24v and use a dropper for the 12v thing. However, the problem of using two batteries in a 12v vehicle it's better to keep them parallel and use a split-charge device. The problem of getting a strong 24v supply from a 12v vehicle can be a headache, I've seen vehicles set up with 3 batteries & 2 alternators and the systems run side-by-side. But that's mostly prats with 24v electric winches and too much money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work fine as long as gray and brown wires are not present at the same time.

The diodes are redundant, they don't fix anything - they will prevent a short-circuit present when both green and brown wires are attached, but the output won't be 12V.

I don't see why you simply won't keep the 12V parallel connection of batteries and charge them from a 12V charger?

Let's not forget that the ideal charging situation is when each battery cell is handled by an individual charger. In a 12V lead-acid battery there are 6 cells, each with 2.0V nominal voltage. Ideally, the cell-to-cell links would be exposed, and one would use a 7-wire connection to the battery for both charging and discharging (with a charge/discharge controller). This is the ideal scenario and maximizes battery life. This is how electric cars and professionally designed battery packs are made (in contrast to cheap junk).

So, even the situation with a 12V battery used as a unit is less than ideal since there's 6 cells in series, without individual cell management. By connecting two of the batteries in series, you're making things even worse.

Answer (score 0):

On the second diagram why don't you add the fifth diode between battery A and B so that the power supplied from D4 & D2 doesn't short the 12V output/motor output due to the grey wire that connects the two wires D2&D4. I think the fifth diode can separate the and allow the flow of series to flow from negative to positive which is a normal flow of series connection. Not 100% sure but its just a suggestion.

Comment: Hi and welcome to EE.SE. "Not 100% sure but its just a suggestion." is not something which would constitute a good answer. Moreover, the question is over three years old and already have an accepted answer.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  Please take the tour at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.  Ditto, @winny.

Answer (score 0):

I think It would work if the 12v output was connected to only 1 battery you could wire a second 12v output to the other battery I'm looking into this for my camp trailer solar setup

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. I think you're using 'Answer' on this site like 'Reply' is used on other discussion sites. Although well-intended, this is a comment and not an answer. It will most likely be deleted but you can delete it yourself before any downvotes reduce your Reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use diodes as those will prevent the 24 V charger from charging the batteries correctly.
2. Use switches as advised, or power connectors (my personal choice) to switch between series and parallel configuration.
3. Adittionally, put a correctly rated fuse in series with each of the batteries since batteries really are quite dangerous.